# Javascript on mobile os, android and ipad

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile

Hello
I am trying to do a javascript function compatible on android and ipad, but i notice that android doesnt support ongesture**** events? 
1.It's really true?

```
.ongesturestart=function(e){
.ongesturechange=function(e){
.ongestureend=function(e){
```

2.Since I cant buy niether an Android system nor a Ipad, is there any Android/Ipad simulator for pc/windows/linux around the web? I need them for developenig and simulating web application based on touch/gestures events.

3.Is there possible that google hasnt develop chrome for android platform? and firefox for android/Ipad?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) These are new events added to iOS's version of WebKit. They haven't yet propagated to Android.

2) There is an Android simulator as part of the Android SDK. The iPad simulator is Mac only. But neither will tell you the true performance of your code--you *need* a device to accurately test your work.

3) Chrome is a desktop browser; Android's built-in browser is roughly equivalent. Firefox is a third-party browser and Google is not responsible for developing it. *The very first hit for the Google search "firefox android", however, is a link to a Firefox Android beta.* Search engines are your friends.

Comment: before posting i search on the web, but i didnt get good results. I see that android supports touchmove touchend and touchstart but not gestures (supported by ipad). I am not worried about the performance (since i write code for performance independent from platform) but for cross-compatibylity. Thanks for the ansewer